# Add mp3 sound in flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

How to add custom mp3 sound in flutter_local_notification, there is a feature of adding custom ringtone but unfortunately no documentation or examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the documentation, there is a lot of information about how you have to handle custom sounds. You need to configure the resource in the android folder and use the config set the sound. Also, you may need to check. how to. work with notification channels. In the source code, there is an example folder with a demonstration of this:

```
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your other channel id',
    'your other channel name',
    'your other channel description',
    icon: 'secondary_icon',
    sound: 'slow_spring_board',
    largeIcon: 'sample_large_icon',
    largeIconBitmapSource: BitmapSource.Drawable,
    vibrationPattern: vibrationPattern,
    enableLights: true,
    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
    ledColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
    ledOnMs: 1000,
    ledOffMs: 500);
```

You can check the full example at https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: @Richardo Markiewicz how do i add sound: 'slow_spring_board' in Show a weekly notification on specific day and time.

Comment: @SOUGATRIYADH You have to add it as an android resource file in android/app/src/main/res/raw/ and the file should be called slow_spring_board.mp3 (or the same name that you pass to 'sound' ended with ".mp3"

Comment: If my notification is showing from the web for example, how can i add an image from the internet and a sound from the internet maybe? Is it a must for the files to be in the res/raw folder?

Comment: Also, be sure your audio file is typed in lowercase or else you'll get a build error.

Comment: "there is a lot of information about how you have to handle custom sounds...." nope there isn't. @Ricardo Markiewicz

Comment: @lordvidex have you found solution about showing sound from internet?

Answer (score 13):

Add raw folder in android project :
android>app>src>main>res> New Android Resource Directory > Select Raw > add your sound here

```
Result Folder :
- android
- app
  - src 
    - main
      - res
        - raw
            lawgo_sound_notification.mp3
```

[image: 1]

implement your local notification code:

```
var androidPlatformChannel = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
    "your_channel_id", "name", "desc_channel",
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('lawgo_sound_notification'),
    playSound: true,
    importance: Importance.Max,
    priority: Priority.High);
```

add onResume, OnLaunch support, when apps run on background notification payload should be setup to this:

```
{ "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification",
     "android_channel_id": "your_channel_id"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
 }
}

**important should add "android_channel_id": "default_notification_channel_id"**
```

Comment: I used this method, but my notification doesn't rings on some devices. And custom sound worked.

Comment: It doesn't say how to register ```androidPlatformChannel``` for background sounds...