# Playing a custom sound in flutter local notifications

Tags: flutter

I have an app that user can select sounds from local storage and set as an alarm sound.How do I pass the sound selected to the local notification.

Comment: I hope you solve this problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324622/add-mp3-sound-in-flutter-local-notifications

Comment: This involves manually putting one sound in the app folders . Only this specific sound will play for notifications. \i am talking about custom sounds that user chooses